# Console Log of Loading NEI Save Files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

NEI (for Minecraft) is a mod that adds in-game functions like spawning in items, changing time and **Saving and Loading Inventories**.

As a moderator on a server, I am concerned as to whether an OP could load an inventory without it showing on the console, could this happen?  Note - I already know that we should not be op'ing people we don't know, but I feel it would be useful to have this answer, we have a set of ops on the premise of knowing whether or not they are spawning items in.

We're currently playing the DNS Techpack, but I do not know whether we have server-side NEI or not.  Would this affect it?

Answer (score 1):

This **does not alert the server**

[image: server log]

Is my log file on the server, nothing is mentioned even though I cloned an entire inventory.